# (C) pointers to function in a struct and functions calls (display info about student struct)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct

So I have an exercise in C++. I have a structure student with the following members: 1 int, 2 char, 1 float and (I write the lines from the exercise): "two pointers on functions for reading data void (*read)(student*st) and one pointer for displaying data void (*write)(student*st) "

I have to read from keyboard the number of students and then to allocate memory for an array with students.

Then I have to define 2 functions: void readData(student* st) and void writeData(student* st) which read and display the members of one student structure. I have to go through students array and to initialize the pointers to functions void (*read)(student*st) and void (*write)(student*st) with void readData(student* st) and void writeData(student* st). Here I am a little bit confused.

The last thing I need to do is to go through students array and to call the functions v[i].read(&v[i]) and v[i].write(&v[i]) to read and display data.

Here is my code:

HEADER

```
 #pragma once

struct student {
    int nrID;
    char name[100];
    char gender[20];
    float mark;
    void(*read)(student* st);
    void(*write)(student* st);
};

void readStudents(int n);
void readData(student* st);
void writeData(student* st);
```

FUNCTIONS FILE

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

void readStudents(int n) {
    cout << "Number of students: ";
    cin >> n;
    student *v;
    v = new student[n]; // here I allocate the students array
    /*
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        v[i].read(??) = readData(&v[i]);
        v[i].write(??) = writeData(&v[i]);
    }
    */ // Here I am confused. I'm not sure if I initialized the pointers to function in a right way.
    
    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i) {
        v[i].read(&v[i]);
        v[i].write(&v[i]);
    }
}
// below I created 2 functions which read and display the members of one student struct.
void readData(student* st) {
    cout << "Enter the nrId: ";
    cin >> st->nrID;

    cout << "Enter the name: ";
    cin >> st->name;

    cout << "Enter the gender: ";
    cin >> st->gender;

    cout << "Enter the mark: ";
    cin >> st->mark;
}

void writeData(student* st) {
    cout << "Id number: " << st->nrID << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << st->name << endl;
    cout << "Gender: " << st->gender << endl;
    cout << "Mark: " << st->mark << endl;
}
```

MAIN FILE

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    readStudents(n);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the code in Code Block and all I have is "Number of students:" the the program crashes.
How to fix those pointers initializations?

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior since the `read` and `write` members of the `struct` have not been assigned to anything valid.

It's not clear to me why `read` and `write` are non-`static` members of the `struct`. It will be better to make them `static` members, assign appropriate functions to them, and then use them to read/write instance of the `struct`.

```
struct student {
    int nrID;
    char name[100];
    char gender[20];
    float mark;

    // make these static members
    static void(*read)(student* st);
    static void(*write)(student* st);
};
```

Make sure to update .cpp file by adding.

```
void (*student::read)(student* st) = nullptr;
void (*student::write)(student* st) = nullptr;
```

Update `main`

```
int main()
{
   // Assign functions to read/write 
   student::read = readData;
   student::write = writeData;

   int n;
   readStudents(n);
   return 0;
}
```